# Text not staying within parent div when 'top' value changed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some images that I want to appear behind my text and I want the text to be centered in the parent div (centered horizontally and vertically), but whenever I change the 'top' value to 50% the text jumps to the top of the page outside of its parent div.

I am using Bootstrap.

```css
.row_comm {
        .community-body{
          position: absolute;
          top: 50%;   
        }
        img {
          display: block;
          width: 100%;
        }
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
 <div class="row row_comm">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-2">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" class="active">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" class="inactive">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" class="inactive">
        </div>
        <div class="community-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-4">
              <h1>Join.</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-5 col-lg-offset-7">
              <p class="lead">Some text.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to assign position relative to the parent of `community-block` so set `row_com` to `position: relative` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

add `position:relative` to the main parent and a width to contain the absolute inside.